# Calling python script from laravel using symfony process component

Tags: python, php, laravel, function, symfony-process

currently im working on project that require me to use python and laravel .I've searched a lot in the internet and apparently the solution to call python function is to use symphony. Im pretty sure that i already tried everything and somehow it doesn't work

Controller

--first try (Using Symfony):

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    function PythonRun()
    {
        $process = new Process(['/usr/bin/python3', 'test.py']);
        $process->run();
        
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
    
        $data = $process->getOutput(); 
        dd($data);      
    }
}
```

-- Second try (Using Exec):

```
    class AdminController extends Controller
{
    function PythonRun()
    {       
       exec("/usr/bin/python3 /python/test.py");       
    }
}
```

Both of them return " The system cannot find speciefied path". i already tried to put the python in the app folder and in the public folder. both doesnt work.

Comment: Where is `test.py` file?

Comment: i tried to put it on the public folder, app folder even on the controller folder of the laravel. none of it work

Comment: pls provide content of test.py to clarrify how you print / output things from your py-file

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with what you want to do and you can run the Python program with any of the possible methods such as exec or using Symfony / process.

But before doing this, you must be sure of things like permissions, etc. for the current user who executes the exec or process command.

Comment: can u give me more detail about the permission etc?. i read it somewhere that u have to chmod something. but cant understand it since im really bad with command promp command